# Enabling preview pane of Windows Explorer for mxd files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, mxd, windows-7

The preview pane in Windows explorer is an efficient way to have sneakpeak at files without having to open them. It works great for a number of file extensions; images, office documents, pdf, dwg files etc.

However, it does not work for mxd files. I usually work around this by having recent exports from each mxd close to it, but now I'm being forced to keep exports in a separate folder.

Is there a way to enable/activate previews for mxd files? I have found [this page](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-more-file-types-explorer) for example, but the method suggested seems only to work if I have an image/video or plain text.

Comment: How about ArcCatalog? or you could develop simple arcengine app to preview the mxd!

Comment: True, didn't think of the preview in ArcCatalog! That can be a reasonable workaround. Off the top of my head I was thinking something along the lines of extracting the thumbnail image to view in Explorer (downside is that I'd have to update it manually). Not sure how to implement that though.

Comment: Can build thumbnail manually https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/metadata/creating-a-thumbnail-for-maps-globes-and-scenes.htm or by using arcpy for batch .makeThumbnail () - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000000n000000. Have also seen a sample for extracting the thumbnail image - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000001nt000000.htm

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov the thumbnails are only available in ArcCatalog. Explorer can not view the thumbnails!  and your last link is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @FaridCher, I understand this :) however, exporting an image of the mxd file and keeping it with the same name in the same folder would let Martin to see the thumbnail :) just another alternative :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to trying to get this to work in non-GIS software like Windows Explorer, I recommend that you simply use the Catalog window of ArcMap to right-click on an MXD and choose Item Description.

[image]

If you leave the Item Description window open then you can just click on other *.mxd files to see their previews loaded.

When you see the one you want, you can drag and drop it into your map the replace the current one.

Comment: I figure this is as close I'll get without creating something myself. Thanks!